# I deleted the namespaces (NS) in my NVMe SSD and Ubuntu is not able to recognize the device

Tags: ssd, pci, nvme

I had two namespaces (NS) in my NVMe SSD (Samsung)
and deleted both to create just one,
but Ubuntu is not able to recognize the device upon deleting. 
How do I recover the drive now?

Command used to delete: `sudo nvme delete-ns /dev/nvme0n1 -n 1`

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Kernel 4.15

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to see `nvme0` in `/dev` -- only the -`nX` entries should be gone.  Try `sudo nvme create-ns -s 100000 -b 4096 /dev/nvme0`, then `sudo nvme attach -n 1 /dev/nvme0`, and see if that gets things working again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, after deleting all namespaces,
this particular NVMe drive's namespaces won't show up under the list of drives
when we use commands like `lsblk`, `fdisk -l` or `nvme list`. 
The reason is that there are no namespaces present on the controller
which are allocated.

But if you run command `ls /dev/nvme*`, it will show the `/dev/nvme0` drive. 
Now you just have to create a namespace using entire capacity
by using the `create-ns` command.  Command is as follows:

If your drive size is 120 GB and block size you want on the drive is 4 KB, you need to calculate number of 4 KB sectors in your 120 GB drive as follows:

*x* = (120 × 1024 × 1024 × 1024) / (4 × 1024) = 31457280

So the command to run is

```
nvme create-ns /dev/nvme0 -s 31457280 -c 31457280 -b 4096
```

After creating the namespace, we need to attach it as follows:

```
nvme attach-ns /dev/nvme0 -n 1 -c 0
```